# Flutter "styled_text" package: how to get (displayed) text from StyledText() widget?

Tags: string, flutter, text, richtext, styledtext

**I have figured out a solution just as I was about to post this question. I will still post it, along with my own answer, to help anyone who might need this in the future**

I use the [styled_text](https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text) package in my project, which makes it easier to create rich text than with the native Flutter `Richtext()` widget.

Have a look at this code example:

```
String name = 'Cedric';
StyledText myStyledText = StyledText(
  text: "Hello <name/>, <b>bold text</b>",
  tags: {
    'b': StyledTextTag(style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    'name': StyledTextWidgetTag(Text(name)),
  },
);
```

The `StyledText` widget in this case would display something that looks like:

Hello Cedric, **bold text**

I don't care about the bold, or italic, color or any other styling attribute right now.
What I need is to be able to get the text that would be displayed by the widget (with my name that I have injected), as a String.
`myStyledText.text` in this case would return `Hello <name/>, <b>bold text</b>`.
What I want to get is `Hello Cedric, bold text`, as a String.

The reason I need this, is because I want to use it in a `Tooltip` widget, which takes a String (and not Widget) parameter `message`, which will be displayed as a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will properly display "Hello Cedric" in the tooltip.

```
Tooltip(
  triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
  showDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  // message: 'message test',
  richMessage: WidgetSpan(
      child: StyledText(
    text: "Hello <name/>",
    tags: {
      'name': StyledTextWidgetTag(
        Text('Cedric', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
    },
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
  )),
  child: Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.blue),
),
```